# Change ID3 Tags Python 2.7

Tags: python, mp3, id3, mutagen

Hello I've been trying to make something that bulk changes ID3 tags and Mutagen seemed like the way to go but I cannot figure out why the tags are staying put. I get no errors it just doesn't save the details when i open Properties on the MP3 file.

```
def changetags(path, albumart, album, title, artist):
    mp3file = mp3.MP3(path)

    tagged = mp3file.add_tags()

    tagged.add(id3.TIT2(encoding=3, text=title))
    tagged.add(id3.TALB(encoding=3, text=album))
    tagged.add(id3.TPE1(encoding=3, text=artist))
    if albumart != None:
        tagged.add(id3.APIC(encoding=3, mime='image/png', type=3, desc=u'Cover', data=urllib.urlopen(albumart)))
    tagged.save()
```

Regards,
Audi

Comment: If by properties you mean the Windows Explorer Properties dialog box, then it's due to Windows only reading ID3v2.3 tags, but Mutagen writing ID3v2.4 tags. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40972762/after-using-python-mutagen-metatags-not-displayed

Answer (score 0):

When I do this I get an error because `tagged` is `None`.  And that is what I would expect because the `add_tags()` method doesn't return anything.  I think you want something more like:

```
mp3file.add_tags()
mp3file.add(id3.TIT2(encoding=3, text=title))
...
mp3file.save()
```

It's the file object (or actually its`tags` object) that you want to modify and save.

Alternatively you can just create an empty `ID3` object and then save it to a specified path.

On a side note, you might find the EasyID3 class easier to use, particularly if you are thinking of looking at tags in any other sort of file other than MP3.