# after using python mutagen,metatags not displayed

Tags: python, audio, metadata, mp3, mutagen

I wanted to edit the meta data of a bunch of mp3 files,so I used python mutegan.

[The details of the mp3 file before running mutagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hcVy.jpg)

I used this simple code to change the details of the mp3 file.

```
from mutagen.easyid3 import EasyID3
audio = EasyID3("C:/wamp/www/music/songs/showkali.mp3")
audio['genre']='pop'
audio.save()
```

After running the program the details cannot be seen in the properties.

[The details of the mp3 file after running mutagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmBvm.jpg)
I figured out this is due to change in id3 tag version after running the program.The id3 tag version changed from ID3v2.3 to ID3v2.4.So I tried using the code

```
from mutagen.easyid3 import EasyID3
audio = EasyID3("C:/wamp/www/music/songs/showkali.mp3")
audio['genre']='pop'
audio.save(v2_version=3)
```

But still the details are not displayed in the details tab of properties.Can anyone suggest me an solution.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

easyid3 does not support v2.3 atm: https://github.com/quodlibet/mutagen/issues/188

You can work around this issue by doing

`mutagen.id3.ID3("C:\\...mp3").save(v2_version=3)`

after saving with easyid3